# Why can't I define GDAL_DATA in PyQGIS script?

Tags: gdal, pyqgis, python-2.7

I created a PyQGIS standalone script in PyCharm my script use rasters layers but any time to try to run it I take this error message:

```
Warning 1: Cannot find pcs.csv
Warning 1: Cannot find datum.csv or gdal_datum.csv
Warning 1: Cannot find ellipsoid.csv
Warning 1: Cannot find prime_meridian.csv
ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.
```

But I have defined GDAL_DATA in the Windows environment:

[image]

I try to add path in PyCharm:

[image]

And I try to add path with `sys.path.append` and nothing again. I have checked all files in error message is in the GDAL PATH.

Any idea why I can't define GDAL_DATA?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have restarted PyCharm after setting the Windows environment variable
2. Make sure you don't have a space (e.g. "GDAL_DATA ") in the Windows environment variable (I got bit by that last week after copy/pasting an env var name from a web page)
3. The paths you added in PyCharm won't work, that's for python paths not general environment variables. You can set an environment variable on a per script basis in the Run->Edit Configurations...->Your Script run config dialog
4. As a last resort, you can set an environment variable in your script using `os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = r'C:\Program Files\QGIS etc...'`

Comment: hello I have space in path in `Program Files` and `QGIS 2.18` that the problem ?

Comment: edit the path like this `r'C:\ProgramFiles\QGIS2.18\share\gdal` ?

Comment: No, I mean space in the variable name, not the variable value.

Comment: I mean I have space in `path` not in `variable name`

Comment: That doesn't matter

Comment: ok then `GDAL_DATA=C:\ProgramFiles\QGIS2.18\share\gdal` I windows environment ,correct ?not working again and I check run-edit-confi..

Comment: yes in path like this 'C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\etc

Comment: Spaces in your environment variable value (i.e. the path) don't matter.